# Magento Mouse Hover Subcatagory

Tags: javascript, html, magento

I am adding a custom theme and when i add he Subcategories they are displayed at the front page without hovering the mouse to base category.

Like:

```
Home |About | Cafe Motif | "Design portfolio"  Motif Store |Shop Online |Blog | Press |
Contact |
```

In This 'Design Portfolio' is subcategory of 'Motif Store' ....

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Question is How can i show the sub category only when mouse hover's the Motif Store, the base category..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the folders to the right in that case.

If you want for example

Category 1 to have Subcategory 1,Subcategory 2,Subcategory 3 show on hover you should organize your tree like this

```
---Default
----Category1
-----SubCategory1
-----SubCategory2
-----SubCategory3
----Category2
----Category3
----Category4
----Category5
```

[image]
Hope to answer your question!

Comment: Thanx for you answer and Yes, this is Exactlly what i am doing but I am making a custom theme so there is an issue in default javascript so it is not setting dropdown in subcategories. And unable to sort out the reason, i am new on magento aswell.